# parallel error in terminating child processes with devtools::test() but not with devtools::check()

Tags: r, parallel-processing, devtools, testthat

I am [writing an R package](https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/PosteriorBootstrap/) with parallel code

```r
anpl <- function(..., num_cores = 1, ...)

  ...

  theta_transpose <- parallel::mcmapply(anpl_single, 1:n_bootstrap,
                                     MoreArgs = more_args, mc.cores = num_cores)
  ...
```

where `anpl` stands for Adaptive Non-Parametric Learning.

I test the code in `tests/testthat/test_anpl.R`:

```r
test_that("Adaptive non-parametric learning with posterior samples works", {
  ...
  anpl_samples <- anpl(..., num_cores = 2)
  ...
}
```

Calling `devtools::check()` works fine:

```
── R CMD check results ─────────────────────────── PosteriorBootstrap 0.0.1 ────
Duration: 1m 15.1s

0 errors ✔ | 0 warnings ✔ | 0 notes ✔
```

Calling `devtools::test()` shows an error with the parallelisation:

```
══ Results ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Duration: 59.5 s

OK:       21
Failed:   0
Warnings: 0
Skipped:  0
Error while shutting down parallel: unable to terminate some child processes
```

I found [this issue](https://github.com/DavisVaughan/furrr/issues/47) relating to Slurm and is still open, and [this issue](https://github.com/r-lib/processx/issues/113) relating to `processx` where the workaround uses the order of calling `parallel` and `processx` and does not apply here.

What is the problem, and how can I fix it?